# How do you create a different theme for each server in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, skinning

Is there any way w/o majorly rewriting the phpMyAdmin source code to have a different theme chosen based on server?

I see it's easy to change themes, but it applies to all servers.

Reason I'd like to do this is so that when I perform a query on production it shows a different color right there and I won't confuse it with a query on dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tried this but apparently you can configure it by:

> Theme selection
>
> On the Homepage, we can offer a theme
>   selector to users. Setting
>   $cfg['ThemeManager'] to TRUE (the
>   default) shows the selector: To help
>   choose a suitable theme, the color
>   palette icon next to Theme/Style
>   brings us screenshots of the available
>   themes. We can then click on take it
>   under the theme we want. The chosen
>   theme is remembered in a cookie. By
>   default, the remembered theme applies
>   to all servers we connect to. To make
>   phpMyAdmin remember one theme per
>   MySQL server, we set
>   $cfg['ThemePerServer'] to TRUE.

Comment: Don't know how I missed the theme per server. But this is remembered by a cookie? Need it to apply to a whole team of devs, not an individual.

Comment: obviously just shooting in the dark here as I don't have a multiple server phpMyAdmin available, but here's another one you could try: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/themes

Comment: Was trying that as you were writing...After waiting for caches/cookies to clear it worked! Thanks!

Comment: needs to be $cfg['ThemePerServer'] with the ticks, if you are just copying and pasting